wireless network adapter Realtek RTL8815BE on an HP laptop wont work
Just bought this HP 15-fd0 laptop.  Using the Windows device manager i see it has Realtek RTL8815BE wifi6 802.11ax PCIe Adapter.  Using Windows, i can connect to wifi no problem.  I installed Ubuntu 24.04 alongside Windows and when in Ubuntu, the wifi icon does not appear.
I found some older posts about downloading some git repositories but none of them had 8815.  I tried them anyway.  I got one of them to make the wireless icon appear and it found SSID and I entered password but would not connect.
Results from lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net:

Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device
[10ec:b851] DeviceName: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller Subsystem:
Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:88e7] Non-Volatile memory
controller [0108]: Ramaxel Technology(Shenzhen) Limited Device
[1e81:6a02] (rev 03)

sudo modprobe -v rtw89_8851be
modprobe:FATAL: Module rtw89_8815be not found in directory /lib/modules/6.2.0-26-generic
sudo dmesg| grep rtw89_8851be
[no output]
Is there a solution to get the wifi working normally?
Thanks,

Please edit to add results from terminal for lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net

Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:b851]
DeviceName: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:88e7]
Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Ramaxel Technology(Shenzhen) Limited Device [1e81:6a02] (rev 03)

Any results for sudo modprobe -v rtw89_8851be; sudo dmesg| grep rtw89_8851be
